# Upgrading APK minSDK version

Tags: android, publishing, android-version

Just a short question. Let's say I've published an app on the Play Store:

- versionCode = 1
- minSdk = 8

The day after I publish the same app but:

- versionCode = 2
- minSkd = 11

How will the users be affected?
Devices with API level < 11, will continue see first version, or none?
Devices with API level >= 11 will see, only version 2, or both?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devices with API < 11 will not see your app. Existing users with api < 11 will not be able to update, and will be stuck with old version. Users with api >= 11 will see the latest version of your app, ie. the one with versionCode 2.

Users with api >= 11 who have the old version of app installed will be able to update to latest version, ie. the one with versionCode 2. (most devices are set to auto-update apps)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to somehow "mantain" (bugfixing) the old version (<= 11) and meanwhile update the other "branch" (>= 11)?

Comment: Yep.  See [Multiple APK support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Comment: @Jumpa , would be nice if you accept my answer if it helped you :-)